# Move a shared folder and keep the share

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

Is it possible to move a shared folder from one NTFS disk to another in Server 2008, and keep it shared?
Or does the share point have to be recreated?

Answer (score 3):

I've done successfully in Win2008, move "Shared Document" with everything inside from drive "D" to drive "E"

```
(01) C:\MrCMD>REG EXPORT "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares" "a_shares.reg" [enter]

(02) C:\MrCMD>REG EXPORT "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares\Security" "a_shares_security.reg" [enter]

(03) C:\MrCMD>ICACLS "D:\Shared Document" /SAVE "ACL_Shared_Document.txt" /T [enter]

(04) CUT "D:\Shared Document" AND PASTE "E:\Shared Document"

(05) C:\MrCMD>ICACLS "E:" /RESTORE "ACL_Shared_Document.txt" [enter]
```

Or.. Alternatively..

```
(00) C:\MrCMD>ROBOCOPY "D:\Shared Document" "E:\Shared Document" /E /COPYALL /MOVE [enter]
```

But, still create New Share for "E:\Shared Document" with appropriate Sharing Permission.

Thank You. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the folder with no problems, but you will need to recreate the share unfortunately, unless anyone else knows how to, but in my experience, you will need to copy/move the shared folder to the other drive and create the share again.

Comment: The LanManServer service references folders to share by their drive-letter and path. When you move the folder you need to "re-share" in the new location. It should be fairly painless.

Comment: What if I then changed the drive letter of the new drive, and the path was the same?  I seem to recall this coming back to life at some stage.